# Process large scale objects in s3 bucket for monitoring

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have about one billion objects in a bucket. And after applying s3 intelligent tiering, almost 100 million objects are going to archive instant access tier.
For saving further costs, we have decided that we use the deep archive access tier because it is rarely accessed.

For few users who search the old data, we provide the restore APIs to retrieve the objects which is in the deep archive. Since the restoring procedure consists of restoring, restoring-completion, we want to notify the procedure of the steps in the restoring for user to see the processing their request.

To achieve this issue, I have the following architectures and am wondering that is there another good approaches. If not, which solution would be the nice case for my case?

1. Event driven

Since we can get the notification from the event such as `deep archive transition in s3-int`, `restoring`, `restoring-completed`, all the events are going to the `sqs -> lambda -> rds` to store the object metadata for visualize them for users.

I think it is a quite good solution, but my worrying about this is that the more than million events are generated at the first time when deep archive is applied and my suggested architecture can process them with proper throughput.

2. Using s3 inventory

By enabling `s3 inventory`, I can get the all list of metadata for objects by daily or weekly. This is more simple I think. By using this inventory files, If I build a small app which read the file and insert the necessary data to database, then my goal will be achieved. However, I have worried that the inventory files is generated daily (or weekly), then the file have many duplicated information because it lists all the objects' metadata in my bucket. After scanning the content of inventory at the first time, I am only interested in the change capture from previous one, but inventory system is not designed. So scanning inventory files whenever they are generated includes unnecessary behavior I think.

So I need any guidance for my case.

Note that the main point is that the object size is very large (about more than 100 millions to monitor) and their meta information will be monitored in near real-time.

I have researched the `s3 batch operation` but it did not meet my case for certain reasons.

Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Thanks.